# How to limit characters in regex?

Tags: regex

I am trying to achieve scenario like that

2014-000000-01

```
[[0-9]{0,3}\-[0-9]{0,5}\-[0-9]{0,1}]
```

I want restrict user not to insert more or less than 4 characters before dash
After dash he can enter 6 character of less than six and after second dash he can not insert less than or greater than two.

Can any one point out how can i achieve it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: *not to insert more or less than 4 characters* - does that mean *exactly 4 characters*?

Comment: Exactly 4: `{4}`, 6 or less: `{1,6}`, exactly 2: `{2}`.

Comment: Your requirements don't seem to match your attempt but by removing the outermost `[` and `]` you are almost there.

Comment: @lucas Yes exact 4 charaters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the context, you may need to use begin and end anchors. If it's in a validator, sometimes it's implied to match the entire string. If not, it would still match, even if there were more than 4 digits at the beginning, for instance.

Here it is with anchors:
`^\d{4}-\d{1,6}-\d{2}$`

Answer (score 0):

```
/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{0,6}-[0-9]{1,}/
```

http://regex101.com/r/mC2qM4/1